# Impossible to Close Program

Tags: streaming-video

I am working on a project that uses the Raspberry Pi camera, and sends the video data to my computer via gstreamer.

In order to make GStreamer automatically boot I added the GStreamer command to my ~/.bash_profile. This worked, and now GStreamer automatically loads, however this application takes up the whole screen and no longer responds to mouse or keyboard commands (I've tried CTRL+C ) , (CTRL+ALT+ESC), etc...

This means GStreamer is working, but its impossible for me to do anything else with my Pi. I like to be able to turn it off so I can work on the other aspects of my project as well. Can anyone recommend a way I could solve this issue?

Comment: have you tried control z also can you access the cursor while gstreamer is running

Comment: just tried control z. nothing happened. no cursor appears, it just displays the video as fullscreen

Comment: so on boot all you see is a full screen video with no x at the top right or tool bar at the bottom? also is the program sending the data correctly to your computer?

Comment: open another terminal and run the following ps aux  | grep -i gstreamer you will probably get at least two lines back one will be the gstreamer app and the other will be the search command from above. The second column will contain a number that you can use to kill the gstreasmer app with the following command: kill #### where #### is the process number from the previous command.

Comment: Have you tried running gstreamer in the background (add & to the end of the command). This may hurt performance of gstreamer, but you wont know until you try it.

Comment: `ALT+F4` to kill it. Then try starting it in the background as @SteveRobillard suggested.